# Access HTML with ECharts by HtmlUnit

Tags: htmlunit, echarts

I accessed an HTML which includes ECharts code by HtmlUnit.
The `div` `picstr` content is the chart's base64 string.
Problem is: this `div`'s content, in the Java output, is different than the HTML output.
Please help.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<body>
    <div id="main" style="width: 600px;height:400px;"></div>
    <div id="picstr"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var searchStr = location.search;
        searchStr = searchStr.substr(1);
        var searchs = searchStr.split("&");
        var data1 = searchs[0].split("=");
        var data2 = searchs[1].split("=");

        var myChart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('main'));
        var option = {
            title: {
                text: 'ECharts'
            },
            tooltip: {},
            legend: {
                data:['销量', '产量']
            },
            xAxis: {
                data: ["衬衫","羊毛衫","雪纺衫","裤子","高跟鞋","袜子"]
            },
            yAxis: {},
            series: [{
                name: '销量',
                type: 'bar',
                data: data1[1].split(","),
                barGap: 0,
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: function() {
                            return '#ff960d';
                        },
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'top'
                        }
                    }
                }
            } , {
                name: '产量',
                type: 'bar',
                data: data2[1].split(","),
                barGap: 0,
                itemStyle: {
                    normal: {
                        color: function() {
                            return '#18c109';
                        },
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            position: 'top'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }]
        };
        myChart.setOption(option);
        document.getElementById("picstr").innerHTML = myChart.getDataURL({});
    </script>
</body>
```

And here is my Java code:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(2000);
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("http://localhost:8888/lab/test.html?d1=5,20,36,10,10,20&d2=15,30,40,15,18,30"), HttpMethod.GET);
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(request);
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);

System.out.println(page.asXml());
webClient.close();
```

The HtmlUnit version is 2.31.

The Java code output looks like:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAADuUlEQVR42u3BMQEAAADCoPVPbQwfoAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA........AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOBnqGIAAZdYcO8AAAAASUVORK5CYII=

But the HTML shows:

> data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAlgAAAGQCAYAAAByNR6YAAAgAElEQVR4Xu3dDZQkZX3v8f9TvTPsrjugARE9UY5ywxGMyHb1QPaS........AAAIIIIBALgL/H4qktlN102BEAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

Comment: I tried to get the div content by PhantomJS, wrong result as well.  T_T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe your expectations are a bit to high:

- As far as i can see ECharts is using the html canvas object. The canvas is able to use different backends (context) at least some build in (2d) and an WebGL based. Usually frameworks check the availability of WebGL and falling back to 2d if WebGL is not available.
- HtmlUnit does NOT support WebGL
- As of version 2.31 many of the drawing functions are only stubs without function (e.g. the whole path stuff). Patches are welcome.
- Think about getDataURL() as some kind of snapshot tool. This call makes a pixel based snapshot of the current content shown in the canvas (including conversion of grey scale or gradients and...). I think this pixel image might already differ if you compare the output from different browsers.
- As far as i remember the browsers are using different color models and color deeps when generating the image; another reason why the browser results might be different already.
- And finally HtmlUnit does not support all the fancy features the canvas (backend) offers at the moment. The idea is to create some kind of visual that comes close to the one in real browsers. (If you miss something here please open an issue (including a simple sample) and i will try to add the missing impl)

To sum it up, i think comparing the getDataURL() results is not really a good (stable) criterion to test the chart.

Comment: Thank you for your message.**Selenium** can implement that and I have tested successfully in WindowsOS.I will try it in Linux.

Comment: Have added one more topic about the status of the current impl in HtmlUnit. Will be great if you have some time and support us in implementing the path support.